# Pandas is Trying to convert my path to a float when inputing to csv cell?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to save a path into a cell of a csv file for reference, but it's giving me error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: *[path]*
class Program:

```
def __init__(self, master):
        self.data = pd.read_csv("SourcingPython\\ProgramData.csv")
        if pd.isnull(self.data.User[0]):
            path = os.getcwd()
            fair = path.split("\\")
            for i in fair:
                if i.isdigit():
                    link = i
            self.data.to_csv("SourcingPython\\ProgramData.csv", index=False) 

def inputSelect(self):
    self.data.Input.at[0]= askopenfilename()
    print(self.data.Input[0])
    self.data.to_csv("SourcingPython\\ProgramData.csv", index=False)
    self.inLabel = Label(text=self.data.Input[0], relief=SUNKEN,width=50).grid(row=1,column=1) 
    root.update()
```

Comment: could you specify which line is causing the value error?

Comment: Yes, thank you for replying.

it appears to be

[self.data.Input.at[0]= askopenfilename()

the dataframe appears to be trying to convert my path into a float, from what I gather

Comment: Could you show a minimal example of your CSV file?

Comment: self.data.Input.at[0]= askopenfilename()

Comment: Which line is giving you the error and can we see the full stack trace, please? Also please add a minimal example of your CSV file input and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. For null values- it appears that you don't need to include ".at" to input the values.

so a simple:

```
self.data.Input= askopenfilename()
```

was sufficient for this.

Thank you